# get call for angular2 failed to bind data

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

I am trying to display the records from db using http get call,but finally i am not able to do that and i am not sure where the error was,

My component:

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Control,FormBuilder,ControlGroup,Validators} from '@angular/common';
import { IDetails } from './pro';
import {GetAllList } from './service'

@Component({
    templateUrl: './components/professional/professional.html',
    providers :  [GetAllList]
})

export class Professional {
    details:IDetails[];

    constructor(private _service:GetAllList) { }

    click(){
        this._service.getList()
            .subscribe(details => this.details = details); 
    }
}
```

My service for the HTTP request:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IDetails } from './pro';

@Injectable()
export class GetAllList {
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/getProfile';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IDetails[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)));

    }
}
```

My simple template:

```html
<button click = "click()" >v</button>{{details}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to events you need to use the `(event)='expression'` syntax like this:

```html
<button (click)="click()" >v</button>
<div *ngFor="let detail of details">
    <div>Firstname: {{detail.firstname}}</div>
    <div>Lastname: {{detail.lastname}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: still i am not geeting

Comment: It shows   MLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/getProfile. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.   but  in network it is showing 200 ok

Comment: So it does tell you, that you need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your server response - read more on that here: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Comment: Additionally in PHP adding a CORS header is as simple as putting `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` at the very top.

Comment: How are you serving that PHP file? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: Also did you already try to perform that request with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Comment: after adding the header i am getting the following error ''Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)''

Comment: So `response.json()` is failing. Can you rewrite the `map` to `.map((response: Response) => { console.log(response); return <IDetails[]> response.json(); })` and tell me what it says?

Comment: still getting [object object]

Comment: console----------------------

Comment: {_body: "↵↵[{"firstname":"raj","lastname":"k","profilename"…k","phone":"8686325014","email":"raj@gmail.com"}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: a…}_body: "↵↵[{"firstname":"raj","lastname":"k","profilename":"raj_k","phone":"8686325014","email":"raj@gmail.com"}]"headers: aok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 2url: "http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/getProfile"__proto__: Object

Comment: Okay great, this looks good. To display an array in the template you need to use `*ngFor`.

Comment: ohh great finnaly i got it thank you so much for u r support